# Create ReactJS class without constructor and binding error

Tags: reactjs

I am using the following code but when I type text in the box, it displays error which doesn't give much information. My goal is to be able to type and display text in the text box.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import { Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import PhotoCamera from '@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera';
import Videocam from '@material-ui/icons/Videocam';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const styles = (theme) => ({
    input: {
        display: 'none'
    }
});

class MediaCapture extends Component {
    state = {
        topText: '',
        bottomText: '',
    };    

    handleChange (event) {
      const {name, value} = event.target
      this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>                
                <Card >
                    <CardContent >
                      <TextField
                        id="standard-name"
                        label="Top Text"
                        name = "topText"
                        value={this.state.topText}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        margin="normal"
                        variant="filled"
                      />                      
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MediaCapture);
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring `handleChange` as an arrow function, which automatically binds its `this` to the current context (the same thing that using `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in the constructor does)

```
handleChange = (event) => {
```

Comment: This should fix the problem. Also to mention the arrow functions are just created once but "normal" functions created for every instance of this class. For this reason arrow functions can't be overidden, but the memory footprint is much smaller.